# how to associate secret manager credential with RDS database

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Using following terrform scripts , i can easily create secret in AWS, but don't find the way to link it with my existing RDS.

How can i create "**Credentials for RDS database**" secret?
following code creates only "**Other type of secrets**". In terraform document, i don't find any option to associate secret with RDS database.

```
  resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "my_secret" {
   name = "mydbsecret"
   }

    locals {
     my_data = {
      username = "username"
      password = "userpassword"
      }
    }


    resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "my_secret_version" {
    secret_id     = aws_secretsmanager_secret.demo_secret.id
    secret_string = jsonencode(local.my_data)
    }
```

Comment: You can't find it, because there is no such option. What do you want to achieve?  Also with that setup, your secret will be in plain text in state file, which may not be a good idea.

Comment: i want create  "Credentials for RDS database", i can do it using AWS Console. but in terraform there is no such options.

Comment: You already have `locals.my_data.username` and password, so use that as your password for rds. What's wrong with that?

Comment: how credentials will associate with RDS?

Comment: You specify the credentials for example in your aws_db_instance resource.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible on a direct way, e.g. by specifying a certain parameter, but you can handover an associative array to the `aws_secretsmanager_secret_version` resource.
This would look like this:

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "rds_credentials" {
  secret_id     = aws_secretsmanager_secret.rds_credentials.id
  secret_string = <<EOF
{
  "username": "${aws_rds_cluster.default.master_username}",
  "password": "${random_password.master_password.result}",
  "engine": "mysql",
  "host": "${aws_rds_cluster.default.endpoint}",
  "port": ${aws_rds_cluster.default.port},
  "dbClusterIdentifier": "${aws_rds_cluster.default.cluster_identifier}"
}
EOF
}
```

The origin of this solution is this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67927860/5945444) from  [@Evan Closson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/699243/evan-closson). Hope that helps and credits to Evan for that example.